# document.write from external script not executed in an iframe created with javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, iframe

I want to add and remove an iframe to a document using javascript / jquery (actually the iframe should be added and also removed if the user chooses to close it).

In this iframe, I have to include an external script using the  element, script that contains basically generated content displayed using document.write (ad rotator).

The problem I have is that when the iframe is loaded, the  element is included but its content is not "interpreted", so that the content is not write with document.write.

I don't know what I am missing here.

Here is what I tried (inspired from other answers on SO):

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script src="jquery-10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="frame.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Some content</div>
        <div id=myFrameContainer>​</div>​​​​​​​
    </body>
</html>
```

frame.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('<iframe></iframe>', {name:"myFrame",id:"myFrame"})
        .css("height", 300)
        .css("width", 500)
        .load(function() {
            $(this).contents().find("body")
                .append('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/rotator.php?affid=12345"></scr' + 'ipt>');
            }).appendTo("#myFrameContainer");
});
```

I also tried to append the  element to the head and also without any success.

On top of this, I can see the content generated by the external script in Firebug (but maybe this is totally normal and has nothing to do with my question).

Comment: Have you tried `.contents().get(0).write(…)` instead of `.append()`?

Comment: Yes I just tried and it didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

`document.write` is only available while the page is being loaded or after calling `document.open`. It cannot be used from a script appended later, as you're doing in `frame.js`.

Comment: So there is no way to do this?

Comment: Last time I had something that used `document.write`, I used this technique: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13775353/2101267